Connection between mean update in CMA-ES and gradient of expected fitness
I currently learn about black-box optimization and CMA-ES. Now, I try to understand some of the theoretical foundations of it. The update of the mean in classic CMA-ES is as follows:
$$m \leftarrow m + c_m \sigma \sum_{i=1}^{\mu} w_i y_{i:\lambda},\text{ where } \ y_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, C)$$
There are some papers now that draw parallels between CMA-ES and natural-gradient-based methods e.g. exponential evolution strategies, which update the mean of the distribution as follows:
$$m \leftarrow m + \eta_m \sum_{i=1}^n u_i · z_i,\text{ where } z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$$
Here, $u_i$ are utility values that are essentially some transformed fitness scores. The authors themselves (Glasmachers et al., 2010) state:

The update [of the mean] is very similar to the update of the center of the search distribution in CMA-ES. The utility function exactly takes the role of the weights in CMA-ES, which assumes a fixed learning rate of one.

I understand that the updates are similar and that one could easily construct a fitness transformation such that $u_i$ and $w_i$ will match. However, I am confused by the fact that NES (of any kind) uses whitened samples for the updates of the mean, while CMA-ES does not. Theoretically, the usage of whitened samples in NES makes sense because this is just the natural gradient of the mean.
My question is therefore: Why is it not deemed a problem that CMA-ES does not whiten the samples for the update of the mean, or is this happening
Sources:
Hansen, Nikolaus. “The CMA evolution strategy: a comparing review.” Towards a new evolutionary computation. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2006. 75-102.
Glasmachers, T., Schaul, T., Yi, S., Wierstra, D., & Schmidhuber, J. (2010, July). Exponential natural evolution strategies. In Proceedings of the 12th annual conference on Genetic and evolutionary computation (pp. 393-400). ACM.

The mean update of NES and CMA-ES are the same up to the choice of weights. It may be that you stumbled over a typo in the Glasmachers et al 2010 paper. The mu-update in Algorithm 1 is the correct update, whereas in Equation (8) it looks like a transformation (the un-whitening so to speak) is missing.

Ah this makes a lot of sense thank you! After looking for answers on my own I also found the nice paper by Akimoto et al: Bidirectional relation between CMA evolution strategies and natural evolution strategies, which helped me a lot.
